# Alternative of JSTL tags in JSF

Tags: jsf, if-statement, jstl

I want to use conditional css in my datatable. Here is my code.

```
    <ui:repeat var="myVar" value="#{bean.list}" varStatus="row">
        <c:if test="#{row.index % 2 == 0}">
            <c:set value="RowColorGrid" var="rowClass"></c:set>
            <c:set value="ArticleColor" var="articleClass"></c:set>
        </c:if> 
        <c:if test="#{row.index % 2 != 0}">
            <c:set value="RowColorGrid2" var="rowClass"></c:set>
            <c:set value="ArticleColor2" var="articleClass"></c:set>
        </c:if>
    <tr>
       <td> Some value </td>
       <td class = "#{articleClass}">
           <h:dataTable id="myId" value="#{bean.value}" var="myVO" width="100%"
                    rowClasses="#{rowClass}">

                         ----Some code---
           </h:datatable>
      </td>
 </ui:repeat>
```

But in JSF i don't want to use JSTL tags. Is there any other alternative for this? using some component of JSF???

I want to use one class in td and one in row class of data table.

Thanks in advance.
Tarun Madaan

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In your specific case You can try something like

```
rowClasses="#{(row.index % 2 == 0)?'RowColorGrid':'RowColorGrid2'}"
```

Comment: Such a simple solution. But didn't click me. Anyways thanks :) Its done now :)

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you do this check server side, inside your managed bean?

then, you get back the "rowClass" property as:

```
String getRowClass() {
  [your checks]
  return rowClass;
}
```

Comment: Thanks 4 ur answer but i can't do that server side. Updated my ques for more clarification. Please have a look again.